# json_decode не считывает русские символы из файла

Tags: php, json

Прошу помочь знатоков PHP. Пытаюсь считать json файл:

```
{
"logo": {
    "position":"right", 
    "width":"180"
},
"image": {
    "size":"big"
},
"menu": {
    "items":"Русский"
}
}
```

PHP-код:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$file = file_get_contents('tegs.json', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
$obj = json_decode($file, true);
print $obj["logo"];
```

Когда удаляю русские символы из файла, всё считывается и работает. Но с кириллицой не дружит.  Кодировка php-файла - utf-8. Кодировки json-файла перепробовал разные: ANSI, Unicode, Utf-8.

Comment: покажи содержимое в `file_get_contents`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала, проверьте кодировку вашего контента с помощью следующей конструкции

```
$is_valid_utf8 = mb_check_encoding($file, 'utf-8'));
```

**mb_check_encoding** Возвращает **TRUE** в случае успешного завершения или **FALSE** в случае возникновения ошибки.

Проверьте, что файл json обязательно в формате UTF-8 без BOM! Если не представляется возможным перекодировать его в формат UTF-8 without BOM (например Notepad++: меню кодировки - преобразовать в UTF-8 без BOM), то можно вырезать его вот так перед json_encode:

```
if(substr($file, 0, 3) == pack("CCC", 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF)) {
    $file = substr($file, 3);
}
```